# What is the difference between in email and by email?

Tags: grammar

I have learnt it {**in**|**by**} email which was sent by my boss.

Comment: If you're talking about a particular email message, use `in an email`. If you're talking about the system of sending messages, use `by`. As in, "He informed me by email"

Comment: The use of "email"  (meaning an individual message) as a count noun is as repugnant to me as the use of "mail" as a count noun for a single letter or package. One never hears anyone say  "I got a lot of mails at my house yesterday." or "The mailman had only one mail for me today."  EMAIL is a mass noun; email message is a count noun.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I'm curious about the extent of your repugnance: do you flinch whenever you hear someone say "emails" instead of "email messages" ? If someone is talking about multiple messages and refers to them as "the email from my boss" it could lead to a listener wondering "which one?"

Comment: Yes, I flinch, and yes, it is ambiguous. That's why, if you mean one message, you should say it was one message.

Comment: @mikeyreilly to what am I referring when I say "I didn't have her e-mail"?

Comment: @phoog Like most people, I'm fine with allowing email as a count noun so it sounds very much like you mean "I didn't have her e-mail message". If I lived in a world where the usage of email as a count noun was unknown then I suppose I would have to conclude you meant something like "I didn't have any of her e-mail messages".

Comment: @mikeyreilly that's what I thought it meant, too, until I read the second half of the sentence, which I have unfortunately forgotten.  This was nonsense if the first part was referring to a message, but it made perfect sense if the first part meant "I didn't have her e-mail address."  Ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

- "I learnt/learned it **from an email message** my boss sent me."

In this phrasing, "from" means "based on" and "email message" is the specific instance of communication.

Or

- "I learnt/learned [of] it **by email** from my boss."

In this phrasing, "by" means "via " and "email" describes the method of communication. (There might have been more than one message.) This says not only that *the email was from your boss*; it says you *learned it* from your boss, *by means of* email.

Or

- "I learnt/learned [or *read*] it **in an email message** from my boss."

Again, here "email message" is the single instance of communication.

Comment: In the second case, directly using "via" seems more natural.